# Как с помощью обработчика событий добавить в массив более одного элемента?

Tags: javascript

Создал два инпута: в один вводиться пароль, другой - кнопка, которая при клике на нее создает объект с массивом из пароля. Но при вводе нового пароля и нажатии на кнопку, старый пароль в массиве стирается, а я хотел бы, чтобы они хранились через запятые. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

```
    <input type="password" id="pswrd">
    <input type="button"  id="btn" value="Создать объект">

    <script>
        btn.onclick = function () {
            var pass = document.getElementById('pswrd').value;
            var Obj = {
                userPasswords: [],
                userPass: function(value) {
                if (value.split('').length < 8) {
                    return 'Длина пароля должна составлять не меньше 8 символов';
                } else {
                    this.userPasswords.push(value);
                    return this;
                }
               }
            };
            console.log(Obj.userPass(pass));
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var Obj = {
  userPasswords: [],
  userPass: function(value) {
    if (value.split('').length < 8) {
      return 'Длина пароля должна составлять не меньше 8 символов';
    } else {
      this.userPasswords.push(value);
      return this;
    }
  }
};
btn.onclick = function () {
  var pass = document.getElementById('pswrd').value;
  console.log(Obj.userPass(pass));
};
```

Comment: Спасибо) Я и забыл, что каждый раз функция перетирает все)